# Sending message to whatsapp contacts

Tags: android

I recently tried the code to send message to whatsapp using intent. But i was wondering if there's any way to directly send the message with the intent action rather than having the text typed in the message box of that contact once a contact is selected. I want the text to be sent to the contact once i select it.

Answer (score 0):

Whats app provide 2 methods to send messages:

1. Custom URL Scheme
2. Android intent system

## Custom URL Scheme

Opening *whatsapp://send?text=* followed by the text to send, will open WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text.

Eg:

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%20World!">Hello, world!</a>
```

## Android intent system

Like most social apps on Android, WhatsApp listens to intents to share media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example, and WhatsApp will be displayed by the system picker:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

More information can be found on [WhatsApp Faq](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012) and on [Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

Comment: Is there no way to directly send the message instead of just having a pre filled message box?

Comment: Seems like you can't avoid the message box. But you can bypass the system picker, so that you directly share to whats app using setPackage in your intent.

Comment: But how can Google now send messages automatically?